# Is it possible to upload python package on PyPI using OpenID?

Tags: python, pip, pypi, python-wheel, twine

I can see that we can create account on PyPI using OpenID as well. Can we also upload python packages to PyPI server using OpenID? Something like generic upload procedure by creating .pypirc file and using PyPI username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Setup username and password at PyPI and use them in your `.pypirc`.

Comment: Agreed. Verified the same at other places as well.